# Cannot disable Directory Listing in httpd.conf

Tags: apache, apache2, xampp, lamp, httpd.conf

I just installed XAMPP on my personal CentOS box and when I try to disable `Directory Listing` I get an Apache error when restarting. My `httpd.conf` file looks like this after I make the changes:

**httpd.conf**

```
Alias /bitnami/ "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs/"
Alias /bitnami "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs"

<Directory "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs">
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**Error**

```
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
AH00526: Syntax error on line 5 of /opt/lampp/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:
Either all Options must start with + or -, or no Option may.
```

I have tried removing Indexes all together and I can still see my directories. Maybe I'm in the wrong file, but from what I've read disabling directory listing has to be made here or .htacces (which I am trying to avoid.) In case it comes up I have made sure to restart XAMPP every time I made changes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear.  To rephrase / show examples:

```
# relative to whatever lower precedence section applies
Options -Indexes
```

If your goal is to turn off indexes.  If you want to make sure FollowSymlinks is also set, put a + in front of it:

```
# relative to whatever lower precedence section applies
Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks
```

If you want to turn everything but FollowSymlinks off:

```
# not relative
Options FollowSymlinks
```

Comment: in apache/conf/httpd.conf replace 'Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI' with 'Options FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI' save and restart apache.

Answer (score 2):

Please go to file: /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf 
and either comment the line like this:

```
#Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
```

or edit like this

```
Options -Index
```

For Windows machine: Do same editing in file /apache/conf/httpd.conf

Comment: In Ubuntu XAMPP **/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf**, This solution worked.
#Options **Indexes** FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI **to** #Options  FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

Comment: @VigneshWaran: Glad that it helped you !

Answer (score 0):

I put a "+" in front of word "FollowSymlinks" to have success.
And replace this lines:

```
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
```

To:

```
Require all granted
```

I hope to help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
sudo a2dismod autoindex
```